# Arrays. Mean Images. Data Analysis

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, mean

**The Analysis**: In short, I'm looking for deforestation rates using scatterometer data. To do this I need to load in all the data (941 .sir files) into an array. Each .sir file represents 4 days of data. I then use this array to find the mean and standard deviation. To detect changes in vegetation, I need to determine and remove the seasonal mean.  Then I'll estimate the standard deviation of the data and with a threshold related to the local std, and identify areas with large changes (high std) in a given year. These area areas of significant change, which may be associated with deforestation. The high threshold value is to remove the ocean. The low one is the key -- to reliably see change, it must be larger than 3 times the standard deviation.

**The Issue/Problem**: I can't figure out how average and then store 7 files of data (28 days so about a month) into an array.

**The Goal**: Get the difference between the means of each month (7-8 .sir files) and store these values into an array for comparison.

[image: Example]

Trying to do this:

> 1) Populate a 3D matrix/array. Preallocate the array. Set up a counter
>   variable. Cycle through every 7th file (e.g., names(1:7:end)) and plug
>   it into the matrix using the counter as the index for the third
>   dimension:
>   myMat(:,:,counter) = loadsir(...);
>   counter = counter + 1;

Entire code actually looks like this:

```
%monthly avg test
%N=floor(length(fname)/7);
%dayv = zeros(7,x2-x1+1,y2-y1+1);
%for i=1:N
  %tmp2=zeros(size(tmp));
  %M=min(7,length(fname)-((N-1)*6+1));
  %for j=1:M
    %ii=j+(i-1)*7;
    %tmp = loadsir(fname(ii).name);
    %tmp2=tmp2+tmp/M;


x1=495;
x2=600;
y1=394;
y2=501;

meanArray = zeros(1,941);
fname = dir('*sir');
[tmp, head] = loadsir(fname(1).name);
dayh = zeros(length(fname),x2-x1+1,y2-y1+1);

%use temporary array to simplify 3d array creation
for i=1:length(fname)
   tmp = loadsir(fname(i).name);
   dayh(i,:,:) = tmp(x1:x2,y1:y2);
end

% create mean and standard deviation images
av=squeeze(mean(dayh,1));
st=squeeze(std(dayh,1));

%store means into an array
meanArray(:,:) = av;

% display mean image
figure(1)
imagesc(av)
colorbar;

% display std image
figure(2)
imagesc(st)
colorbar;

% High threshold = bad data
ThresH=0.35;
% Low threshold = area of significant change
thresL=st*3;

% create copy of mean image
img=av;
% apply threshold
ind= st>ThresL & st <ThresH;
img(ind)=0; % set to high value to make more visible
ind=find(st>=ThresH);
img(ind)=-30; % discard very high variance areas

% display image with significant change indicated
figure(3)
imagesc(img)
colorbar;
```

If anyone wants to help they can add me on gtalk: exzacklyright@gmail.com I need to finish this by Friday preferably so I have time to setup a presentation by next Monday.